# Jquery .when().then() or just straight function calls. any difference?

Tags: jquery

I was doing some coding and came across this and I realize I do not need when().then(), but curious IF it would be useful in this case...

```
var someObj = function(){

  var k = {
     a: function(){ 
           // do something 
     },
     b: function(){ 
        // do something
     },
     c: function(){ 
       // do something
     },

     dolast: function(){
        // something that needs to happen last
     }
 }
 return k;

}();
```

so, because I want dolast() to fire last, I figurd to do:

```
jQuery.when(
        (function(){
           someObj.a();
           someObj.b();
           someObj.c();
          })() 
        ).then(
          someObj.dolast();
        )
```

AND that does exactly the same thing as this:

```
   someObj.a();
   someObj.b();
   someObj.c();
   someObj.dolast();
```

when I console out values and such. So, if none of my functions are returning promises, does it matter to use when/then or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use promises in general or `jQuery.when()` if your code is 100% synchronous.  To do so is just making things far more complicated and slower than required.

If you want to execute four synchronous functions in a row one after the other, just call them that way.  Javascript will execute the first and when it returns, execute the second and so on.

So this:

```
someObj.a();
someObj.b();
someObj.c();
someObj.dolast();
```

is a perfectly fine and simple way of executing your four methods in a prescribed order one after the other.  Javascript executes statements in order one after the other.

Now, if one or more of those methods fired off something that was asynchronous (like an ajax call) and the method returned a promise and you wanted to sequence other things relative to when the ajax calls finished sometime in the future, then you would have a need for things like promises and perhaps `jQuery.when()`.  But, for 100% synchronous code, there is no need to complicate matters by using promises.

---

If each of these methods returns an success/error code (let's say `0` is success) and you want to only proceed with the rest if they are successful, then you can do something like this:

```
function runSequence(obj) {
     var err;
     if ((err = obj.a()) !== 0) return err;
     if ((err = obj.b()) !== 0) return err;
     if ((err = obj.c()) !== 0) return err;
     return obj.doLast();
}
```

Or, if you code your methods to throw an exception when they fail, you can do this:

```
function runSequence(obj) {
    try {
        someObj.a();
        someObj.b();
        someObj.c();
        someObj.dolast();
        return 0;
    } catch(e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Or, using a data driven approach:

```
function runSequence(obj, arrayOfMethods) {
    var err;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfMethods.length; i++) {
        err = obj[arrayOfMethods[i]]();
        if (err !== 0) return err;
    }
    return 0;
}

runSequence(someObj, ["a", "b", "c", "doLast"]);
```

Comment: Hey - I have an additional questions => What if I want to be able to short circuit eveything if during one of the function calls, there is an issue with data or whatever, and I 'return false': can I then break out of everything and not continue the function calls, including the "then". If I need that to happen, would I use deferreds? IF so, example?

Comment: @user1492442 - You can abort execution of the other functions that come after by either returning an error code (and then checking for that code) or throwing an exception (and then catching the exception the right point).  This is still no reason to use promises/deferreds?  They only offer you something additional when dealing with asynchronous operations.

Comment: I see, so setting some global error code to my object and thus checking against that... thanks. I'll go that route!

Comment: @user1492442 - global error codes are usually a bad idea.  I would suggest that each method that wants to abort the sequence just returns a success/error code and you check that before running the next step.

Comment: @user1492442 - I added a couple examples of sequence error handling.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you don't use Deferred features here and if you need to just call some functions in some specific order - just do it. Overcomplicating your code makes it less maintainable. [Keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).